# Can the number of clusters generated by DP_GP_cluster be reduced or set manually?

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have been utilizing the package [DP_GP_cluster](https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/DP_GP_cluster) to identify trends in gene expression data over several time points in two datasets with several thousand genes each. For one dataset I generated 28 clusters, but I am wondering if this number can be reduced or set manually. Any assistance on this point would be appreciated!

I have two datasets, and running the package normally produced 28 clusters and 19 clusters respectively. I haven't been able to find any information on how to set or reduce the number of clusters generated.

EDIT: The script I have been submitting.

```
module load anaconda/py3
source activate dpgp
cd /scratch/scwalls/DP_GP_cluster
```

```
python bin/DP_GP_cluster.py -i KAP4_orthos_only/KAP4_CON21_orthos_counts_for_clustering.txt -o KAP4_orthos_only/output_final_KAP4_orthos -p png --plot --fast
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.